# Complex Equation Of a Circle $|z-z_1|^2+|z-z_2|^2=k$.

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

> If $z_1$ and $z_2$ are fixed and satisfies $|z-z_1|^2+|z-z_2|^2=k$
>   what are the possible values of k so that this equation represents a
>   circle?

I tried using pythagoras theorem,that the equation of circle should be $z-z_1|^2+|z-z_2|^2=|z_1-z_2|^2$.

So k should be $|z_1-z_2|^2$.But the answer is given is $k>\frac{1}{2}|z_1-z_2|^2$.Where am I going wrong?How to approach the problem (preferably geometrically) ?

Comment: "I tried using pythagoras theorem,that the equation of circle should be $z-z_1|^2+|z-z_2|^2=|z_1-z_2|^2$." This is impossible to decipher, please explain what you did.

Comment: How did you apply Pythagoras theroem ?

Comment: Ok see let z1 and z2 be 2 points.Angle in a semicircle is 90 degrees.For z to lie on a circle whose diameter's end points are z1 and z2 then |z-z1|,|z-z2| and |z1-z2| are sides of a right triangle.

Comment: who said that  the diameter should  have  z1 and z2 as end points  ?

Comment: Ok so that was the mistake @Nizar..

Comment: I think what you would do here is first assume that the points are diameter points and then find the value of k . So we get a bound on the value of k. Now if you consider those making any other triangle you will find that the value of k will be always greater than the bound that we did set.

Comment: What do you mean by  " consider those making any other triangle  " ? @Rememberme

Comment: Consider the points $z_1,z_2,z$ be the points of any other triangle formed which is not right angled

Comment: Then the circumradius that the triangle will have will always be greater than the value of the circumradius our right angled triangle had.@Nizar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let  $z=x+iy$ and  $z_1=x_1+iy_1$ and  $z_2=x_2+iy_2$. Then we have 
 $|z-z_1|^2+|z-z_2|^2=k$ implies  $$ |(x-x_1)+ i (y-y_1)|^2+|(x-x_2)+ i (y-y_2)|^2=k   $$ 
$$ (x-x_1)^2+  (y-y_1)^2+(x-x_2)^2+  (y-y_2)^2=k   $$
Expanding we get  $$ 2x^2 +2y^2 -2x(x_1+x_2) -2y(y_1+y_2)=k-x_1^2 -y_1^2-x_2^2 -y_2^2 $$
divide by 2 we get  $$x^2 +y^2 -x(x_1+x_2) -y(y_1+y_2)=\frac{1}{2}[k-x_1^2 -y_1^2-x_2^2 -y_2^2]  $$
Complete squares on the left hand side 
$$  \Big(x-(\frac{x_1+x_1}{2})\Big)^2 +\Big(y-(\frac{y_1+y _1}{2})\Big)^2  = \frac{1}{2}[k-x_1^2 -y_1^2-x_2^2 -y_2^2]  + \frac{1}{4}(x_1+x_2)^2+ \frac{1}{4}(y_1+y_2)^2$$ This implies 
$$\Big(x-(\frac{x_1+x_1}{2})\Big)^2 +\Big(y-(\frac{y_1+y _1}{2})\Big)^2  =  \frac{1}{2}[k-x_1^2 -y_1^2-x_2^2 -y_2^2 + \frac{1}{2} x_1^2    + \frac{1}{2} x_2^2 +x_1x_2   + \frac{1}{2} x_1^2    + \frac{1}{2} y_2^2   +y_1y_2   ] $$
and so  $$\Big(x-(\frac{x_1+x_1}{2})\Big)^2 +\Big(y-(\frac{y_1+y _1}{2})\Big)^2  =  \frac{1}{2}[k-\frac{1}{2}x_1^2 -\frac{1}{2}y_1^2-\frac{1}{2}x_2^2 -\frac{1}{2}y_2^2 +x_1x_2    +y_1y_2   ]   $$ 
$$\Big(x-(\frac{x_1+x_1}{2})\Big)^2 +\Big(y-(\frac{y_1+y _1}{2})\Big)^2  =  \frac{1}{2}[k-\frac{1}{2} [ (x_1 -x_2)^2  +(y_1-y_2)^2]  ]   $$
i.e. 
$$ \Big(x-(\frac{x_1+x_1}{2})\Big)^2 +\Big(y-(\frac{y_1+y _1}{2})\Big)^2  =  \frac{1}{2}[k-\frac{1}{2}  |z_1-z_2|^2 ]   $$
Note that this has the well known equation of a circle just if having on the right hand side  $r^2$, and so  the term $k-\frac{1}{2}  |z_1-z_2|^2$  should be positive strictly  i.e. $k>\frac{1}{2}  |z_1-z_2|^2$.

Small Remark : If you notice, always the center of your circle is the midpoint between  $z_1$ and  $z_2$. Special case when  $k=|z_1-z_2|^2$, the two points $z_1$ and  $z_2$ are on the circle .

Comment: Well done :-)..

Answer (score 2):

$$|z-z_1|^2+|z-z_2|^2=k\tag{1}$$
let $z=w+\dfrac{z_1+z_2}{2}$ then $(1)$ becomes 
$$|w+\dfrac{z_1-z_2}{2}|^2+|w-\dfrac{z_1-z_2}{2}|^2=k$$
or
$$|w+\alpha|^2+|w-\alpha|^2=k\tag{2}$$
where $\alpha=\dfrac{z_1-z_2}{2}$, from $(2)$
$$2w\overline{w}+2\alpha\overline{\alpha}=k$$
or
$$|w|^2=\dfrac{k}{2}-|\alpha|^2$$
this is the equation of circle $|w|=r$ with $r=\sqrt{\dfrac{k}{2}-|\alpha|^2}$ if $\dfrac{k}{2}-|\alpha|^2>0$ or 
$$\color{blue}{k>2|\alpha|^2=\dfrac12|z_1-z_2|^2}$$