# Find out the condition for $k$ such that the locus of $z$ is a circle.

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $\alpha,\beta$ be fixed complex numbers and $z$ is a variable complex number such that $|z-\alpha|^2+|z-\beta|^2=k.$Find out the condition for $k$ such that the locus of $z$ is a circle.

---

I think,if i take $\alpha,\beta$ as diametrically opposite points and $z$ on the circumference,then the $\alpha,\beta$ subtend right angle on $z$.But i cannot figure out the condition.The answer given is $k>\frac{1}{2}|\alpha-\beta|^2$

Comment: $k >|\alpha |^{2}+|\beta |^{2}$.

Comment: Thanks Martin Roberts

Answer (score 0):

This answer is essentially taken from this duplicate [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1479849/complex-equation-of-a-circle-z-z-12z-z-22-k):

## #

Let  $z=x+iy$ and  $z_1=x_1+iy_1$ and  $z_2=x_2+iy_2$.

Then we have 
 $|z-z_1|^2+|z-z_2|^2=k.$

This implies  $$ |(x-x_1)+ i (y-y_1)|^2+|(x-x_2)+ i (y-y_2)|^2=k   $$ 
$$ \therefore (x-x_1)^2+  (y-y_1)^2+(x-x_2)^2+  (y-y_2)^2=k   $$
Expanding we get  $$ 2x^2 +2y^2 -2x(x_1+x_2) -2y(y_1+y_2)=k-x_1^2 -y_1^2-x_2^2 -y_2^2 $$
$$\therefore x^2 +y^2 -x(x_1+x_2) -y(y_1+y_2)=\frac{1}{2}\left( k-x_1^2 -y_1^2-x_2^2 -y_2^2\right)  $$
Now completing squares on the left hand side, 
$$  \Big(x-(\frac{x_1+x_1}{2})\Big)^2 +\Big(y-(\frac{y_1+y _1}{2})\Big)^2  = \frac{1}{2}\left(k-x_1^2 -y_1^2-x_2^2 -y_2^2\right)  + \frac{1}{4}(x_1+x_2)^2+ \frac{1}{4}(y_1+y_2)^2$$

Expanding the right-hand side gives, 
$$\Big(x-(\frac{x_1+x_1}{2})\Big)^2 +\Big(y-(\frac{y_1+y _1}{2})\Big)^2  =  \frac{1}{2}\left(k-x_1^2 -y_1^2-x_2^2 -y_2^2 + \frac{1}{2} x_1^2    + \frac{1}{2} x_2^2 +x_1x_2   + \frac{1}{2} x_1^2    + \frac{1}{2} y_2^2   +y_1y_2   \right) $$
and so  $$\Big(x-(\frac{x_1+x_1}{2})\Big)^2 +\Big(y-(\frac{y_1+y _1}{2})\Big)^2  =  \frac{1}{2}[k-\frac{1}{2}x_1^2 -\frac{1}{2}y_1^2-\frac{1}{2}x_2^2 -\frac{1}{2}y_2^2 +x_1x_2    +y_1y_2   ]   $$ 
$$\Big(x-(\frac{x_1+x_1}{2})\Big)^2 +\Big(y-(\frac{y_1+y _1}{2})\Big)^2  =  \frac{1}{2}[k-\frac{1}{2} [ (x_1 -x_2)^2  +(y_1-y_2)^2]  ]   $$
i.e. 
$$ \Big(x-(\frac{x_1+x_1}{2})\Big)^2 +\Big(y-(\frac{y_1+y _1}{2})\Big)^2  =  \frac{1}{2}[k-\frac{1}{2}  |z_1-z_2|^2 ]   $$

This expression takes the same format at the equation of a circle if the right hand side  $r^2$.

Thus,  the term $k-\frac{1}{2}  |z_1-z_2|^2$  should be strictly positive.
That is,  $k>\frac{1}{2}  |z_1-z_2|^2$.