# Locus in complex plane for orthogonal intersection

Tags: complex-numbers, locus

Given

$$ |z-a|^2 +|z-b|^2 = |a-b|^2 $$

[image]

where $(a,b,z=OP) $ are complex with a right angle at common point P in the complex  plane. what is the curve it traces? Would the locus be also a circle on diameter $ |a-b|$?

Special case: when $(a,b) $ are real and of same sign  then we have const $\tau$ blue circles and if of opposite sign then we have const $\sigma$ red circles as the required locus:

[Bipolar Coord Loci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_coordinates)

Comment: The locus is always a circle, see for example [Complex Equation Of a Circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1479849/complex-equation-of-a-circle-z-z-12z-z-22-k). The relation is invariant to translations and rotations. so it makes no difference whether $a,b$ are on the real axis or not.

Comment: If you put it up as answer I would accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the [parallelogram law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law)  (or the equivalent [median theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonius%27s_theorem)) written for $\,z-a, z-b\,$:

$$
\begin{align}
2 \big|z-a\big|^2 + 2 \big|z-b\big|^2 &= \big|(z-a)-(z-b)\big|^2 + \big|(z - a) + (z - b)\big|^2
\\ &= \big|a-b\big|^2 + 4\, \bigg|z - \frac{a+b}{2}\bigg|^2
\end{align}
$$

Under the given condition $\,|z-a|^2 + |z-b|^2 = |a-b|^2\,$, so:

$$
2 \big|a-b\big|^2 = \big|a-b\big|^2 + 4\, \bigg|z - \frac{a+b}{2}\bigg|^2 \quad\implies \quad \bigg|z - \frac{a+b}{2}\bigg| = \bigg|\frac{a-b}{2}\bigg|
$$

It follows that the locus is the circle having $\,a b\,$ as the diameter.

More generally, the same argument can be used to prove that the locus of $\,|z-a|^2+|z-b|^2 = c\,$ is a circle centered at the midpoint of $\,a b\,$.

Yet more generally, the locus of points with constant sum of squared distances to $\,n\,$ fixed points is a circle (in 2D, or a hypersphere in $\,\mathbb R^n$) centered at the centroid of those points.